# Three.js - Depth of field

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying make depth of field in my project and I'm inspired from official three.js example like this https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_dof.html

I have problem with method BokehPass. There is my code:

```
const bokehPass = new THREE.BokehPass( this.scene, this.camera, {
  focus: 1.0,
  aperture: 0.025,
  maxblur: 1.0,
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
} );
```

and when I want to initialize it I have error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
```

It's error from third param in this method. Does someone have any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: Please include the full error (source file, line number, etc.), and the version of three.js you're using.

Comment: I have three: 0.87.1 and three-addons: 1.0.2.

Full message error is:

http://imgur.com/c4xDNbM

and this is code of it:

http://imgur.com/ZiFIXi2

Comment: Please include these in your post, preferably as copied text, not screen captures. That said, your error tells you everything. It can't find the `focus` uniform of the shader, so it can't set its value. My guess is you're using `BokehShader2.js` (doesn't have a `focus` uniform), when you should be using `BokehShader.js` (_does_ have a `focus` uniform).